# Can't update database using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to build a very simple "budget" website solely for practice, but I can't make this site update my database.

Basically I have a database 'budgetdb' running in XAMPP with MySQL. I've got 1 table where the structure looks like this:

[image]

I've got two files, 'index.html' and 'handleUserInput.php'.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="description">
    <input type="number" id="budgetin">
    <input type="number" id="budgetout">
    <button type="button" onclick="updateDB()">Add to database</button>

    <script>

        function updateDB() {
            var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
            var budgetin = document.getElementById('budgetin').value;
            var budgetout = document.getElementById('budgetout').value;

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "handleUserInput.php?description='" + description + "'&budgetin='" + budgetin + "'&budgetout='" + budgetout + "'";

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert('Variables sent to server!');
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", url);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

handleUserInput.php:

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "budgetdb"

    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password;
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $budgetin = $_POST['budgetin'];
    $budgetout = $_POST['budgetout'];

    $query = 'INSERT into budget VALUES ($description, $budgetin, $budgetout)';

    mysql_query($query)

    ?>
```

The message prompt is displayed, but no data is shown in the database. Any clue on what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE** chrome error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: description in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/handleUserInput.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: budgetin in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/handleUserInput.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: budgetout in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/handleUserInput.php on line 15
```

Comment: `"INSERT into budget VALUES ('$description', '$budgetin', '$budgetout')"` Check your quotes in your PHP string and MySQL query.

Comment: P.S. This code is *very* unsafe!  Stop using `mysql_query` and learn about prepared statements and MySQLi (or PDO).  http://www.bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have shown the problem with the way you write the query, it. should be, with quotes around each of the values.

```
$query= "INSERT into budget VALUES('$description',$budgetin,$budgetout)";
```

But you also have a problem with the way you create the URL. Quotes shouldn't be put around query parameters, and you should use `encodeURIComponent` to ensure that special characters are escaped properly.

```
var url = "handleUserInput.php?description=" + encodeURIComponent(description) + "&budgetin=" + encodeURIComponent(budgetin) + "&budgetout=" + encodeURIComponent(budgetout);
```

And to prevent SQL injection problems, you need to escape the strings before you use them as SQL parameters. And since you're sending the parameters in the URL, rather than in the `POST` data, you need to get them from `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

```
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['description']);
```

Although if you're first learning PHP now, you should use PDO or mysqli, instead of the obsolete mysql extension, and use prepared statements instead of string substitution.

Change the line that performs the query to:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

If there's a problem performing the query, this will display the error message.

Comment: I see. Changed the quotes now, and it'll definitely be looking into SQL injection - but my example still doesn't work

Comment: Add the error checking that I just put into the answer.

Comment: Did that now, but it doesn't react kind off. After I press the button, it displays the javascript prompt and doesn't do anything else

Comment: Go into Developer Tools, go to the Network tab, select the URL for the AJAX request, and look at the Response to see if there's an error message there.

Comment: Went there now and found the error, but the fix revealed three new errors whereas it cannot find the POST keys. Looking through the request doesn't show any obvious glitches to me, though.

Comment: URL parameters are in `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of any reason.

Comment: Figured it out now, I didn't specify the name of the database in the connection. Works now. Thank you!

Comment: You mean the line `$dbname = "budgetdb";` wasn't actually in the script, like it was in the question?

Comment: I changed from mysql_connect to $conn = new mysqli, and forgot to include $dbname in the new connection

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$query = "INSERT into budget VALUES ('$description', $budgetin, $budgetout)";
```

description is string type in database so you close with single quote or double quote in PHP String.

Always consider safety. ReWrite a code as (somewhat safety):

```
$description = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['description'] );
$budgetin = intval( $_POST['budgetin'] );
$budgetout = intval( $_POST['budgetout'] );

$query = 'INSERT into budget VALUES ("$description", $budgetin, $budgetout)';
```

**Note:** Don't use mysql_* function. It is deprecated in future versions. Use MySQLi or PDO

Comment: You're missing a few quotes and/or `.` operators.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes in your query are incorrect. Should be (note outer double quotes and inner single quotes):

```
$query= "INSERT into budget VALUES('$description',$budgetin,$budgetout)";
```

However, be aware this has opened you up to a SQL injection where description is

```
'); DROP budget;
```

Also, your **description** may contain punctuation and spaces, which may be messing up your url. You are sending a POST anyway, so all the data should be in the body of the request not the url.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your values as **GET** parameters not **POST** parameters.

```
handleUserInput.php?description='" + description + "'&budgetin='" + budgetin + "'&budgetout='" + budgetout + "'"
```

Everything you pass to PHP thru url will fall into $_GET variable. Not only PHP bu every server side language will behave the same, once it is a standard GET means URL parameters and POST is Request Payload

You can change **$_POST** to **$_GET** or add your data do xmlhttprequest object

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="description">
    <input type="number" id="budgetin">
    <input type="number" id="budgetout">
    <button type="button" onclick="updateDB()">Add to database</button>

    <script>

        function updateDB() {
            var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
            var budgetin = document.getElementById('budgetin').value;
            var budgetout = document.getElementById('budgetout').value;
            var params = "description=" + description + "&budgetin=" + budgetin + "&budgetout=" + budgetout;
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp .setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp .setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            xmlhttp .setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

            var url = "handleUserInput.php?";

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert('Variables sent to server!');
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", url,true);
            xmlhttp.send(params);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to minize your code use Jquery library instead of simple JS code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="description">
    <input type="number" id="budgetin">
    <input type="number" id="budgetout">
    <button type="button" onclick="updateDB()">Add to database</button>

    <script>

        function updateDB() {
            var description = $('#description');
            var budgetin = $('#budgetin');
            var budgetout = $('#budgetout');

            $.post( "handleUserInput.php", { "description": description, "budgetin": budgetin, "budgetout": budgetout }, function( data ) {
              alert( "Variables sent to server!" );
            } );

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` in order to avoid SQL injection into your application. Initial problem was caused because php variables wasn't correctly added in the string of SQL query, for example :

```
$input = 'aaa';
echo 'text $input';
```

this code will output

```
text $input
```

but this one

```
$input = 'aaa';
echo "text $input";
```

or this one

```
$input = 'aaa';
echo "text ".$input.";
```

will output

```
text aaa
```

Please check the code bellow

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "budgetdb"

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password;
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$description = $_POST['description'];
$budgetin = $_POST['budgetin'];
$budgetout = $_POST['budgetout'];

$description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
$budgetin= mysql_real_escape_string($budgetin);
$budgetout= mysql_real_escape_string($budgetout);
$query = "INSERT into budget VALUES ('".$description."', ".$budgetin.", ".$budgetout.")";

mysql_query($query)

?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -2):

Use single inverted comma with php variables like below.

```
$query = "INSERT into budget VALUES ('$description', $budgetin, $budgetout)";
```

Comment: You need double quotes around the query, so that variables will be substituted.

Comment: This won't even parse. It contains multiple syntax errors.